# Styling repeating svg background with css

Tags: css, svg

I've been browsing the internet for about 4 hours now and I can't find any solution for my task.

I simply want to set a svg-image as a background and repeat it.  I couldn't figure out how to apply background-repeat etc.
I furthermore want to be able to style the border of the svg with css and/or JS, changing the border-colours once a minute from the left side of the div to the right side of the div. The only thing I know about this: svg border is called `stroke` but I don't know how to use this information.

This is what I got so far:

```
<div id="test">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

        <path d="M69.527,2H29.971L2,29.971v39.558L29.971,97.5h39.558L97.5,69.527V29.972L69.527,2z M95.625,68.898L68.898,95.625H31.101  L4.375,68.898V31.516v-0.414L31.102,4.375h37.796l26.728,26.727L95.625,68.898L95.625,68.898z"/>
        <path d="M68.07,6.375H31.93L6.375,31.93v36.142L31.93,93.626h36.142L93.625,68.07V31.93L68.07,6.375z"/>

    </svg>

</div>
```

and for CSS

```
body {
    background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 1);
}

#test {
    width: 70%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJehi)

Comment: it's still unclear on the behavior of changing the border from left to right.

Comment: please review your question *changing the border-colours once a minute from the left side of the div to the right side of the div.* I don't understand how the border color is changed ***from left to right***? it looks like a transition?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a transition but that is more like the second step. More important for me is being able to set the svg as a repeating background and style the border of each repeating tile.

Comment: sorry. I couldn't imagine how advanced your requirement is. Looks like you should post another question. I would never create such kind of background (it has very poor performance) unless it's used for such as a game.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `background-repeat` to tile your SVG, you will need to save the SVG in a separate file (with proper SVG headers and namespace) and use it as a `background-image`.  The code you present doesn't have SVG as a background, it has the SVG as an element within the main document.  The background repeat property has no more effect on the SVG in this case than it would on an `<img>` element.

As an alternative (if you want to avoid separate files), you could make the SVG fill the entire div, and then use an SVG `<pattern>` to tile the graphic.  I'm sure you could find examples of syntax by searching for "SVG patterns".

Having a style property of each tile change progressively from left to right isn't possible in either of these situations.  Both `background-repeat` and `<pattern>` achieve efficient repetition of a graphic by repeating it exactly, so you can't change one tile at a different time from other tiles.

If the effect is really important to you, the approach most likely to succeed would be to

1. make the entire repeating pattern within SVG
2. create a linear gradient, defined in `userSpaceOnUse` units for the colour transition, and use this as the stroke property
3. animate the gradient using SMIL animation (will not work in IE) or Javascript (more work and more CPU drain)

However, you will have to create the repeating pattern directly, or possibly with `<use>` elements (I haven't tested), rather than a `<pattern>`.  Alternately, you could create two patterns, one for the fill and one for the stroke (in white), and use the results of the stroke pattern as a mask for a rectangle filled entirely with the gradient.

None of this is what I'd consider a beginner SVG example, but if you get it working you'll learn a lot about SVG.